# Prism.Wpf + Elysium.Extra

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I have two test project: 1st for Prism.Wpf, 2nd for Elysium.Extra. Both runs fine. But now I try to use Prism with Elysium in one project.

I have my `class Shell : Framework.UI.Controls.Window` (not `System.Windows.Window`, accordig to elysium's examples) with xaml:
    `<extra:Window x:Class=`   ... etc.

Bootstrapper's CreateShell() method has single row:

```
Container.Resolve<Shell>();
```

When I run my app, this row pass control flow to Shell's constructor, then app fails with exception:

> An exception of type
>   'System.Windows.ResourceReferenceKeyNotFoundException' occurred in
>   PresentationFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional
>   information: 'Framework.UI.Controls.Window' resource not found.

Is it possible to use not System.Windows.Window as Prism's shell? Or it's not cause of exception? Please, help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any custom Window control with Prism.  Your problem is that you didn't change your App.xaml and App.xaml.cs to be an ElysiumApplication, which is where the resource for the Window is defined.